# How to read toast message in appium if toast message is dynamically changing in such cases how to extract using tess4j

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-desktop

Currently in our app for testing purpose dev team is displaying OTP as a toast message there are lot of places in such cases how to automate using appium anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

For automation toast messages refer below url:
https://appiumpro.com/editions/64

But for dynamic content, use tesseract or getpagesource, for more details refer last 3 comments in the below thread:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/verify-notifications-or-toast-messages/17159/15